# Printing to Receipt Printer from Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, point-of-sale

This is more a question if I am taking a 'wrong path' to accomplish the task.

I need to print Data to Receipt Printers from Web Application.

Based on what I understand from various posts on net, it seems best option would be to create something like a Print Server (not sure about the name). This will be  C# desktop application running as a service. I am planning to put messages in queue and Print Server  to pull messages  from queue and print it to reconfigured LAN printers. I will be using POS.NET to connect to POS devices.

Added advantage (to using Javascript/pdf solutions) is that I can enhance the same "Print Server" to  send information to display system. The message system could be decoupled to be on cloud so as to  print in a different geographical area, like warehouse.
If I target Framework 3.5 for the service, I can get rid of POS.NET issues with Framework 4.0 plus versions.

Am I reinventing something that is already available in .Net or possibly an open-source application?

I found these kind of similar questions

- [How to print from web application to receipt printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192502/how-to-print-from-web-application-to-receipt-printer)
- [Configuring a POS printer for remote printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042501/configuring-a-pos-printer-for-remote-printing)

which were helpful but did not answer my question in full.

Answer (score 0):

I had a to do exactly this, and after many hours of searching,  I could not find anything.  I achieved this by installing Thunderbird (any email client will do) and send the receipt via email to the account linked up to that client,  I then setup a rule on the email client to print out anything it recieved.